# alternative to dio_* functions

Tags: php, io

As I noticed in php manual, the Direct IO functions are no more between us. And I am in an urgent need of such a functionality. I don't even know if it will work, but I need to bypass stream wrappers and protocols.

Is there an alternative? Something that will allow to write and read at such a low level?

---

#### EDIT 1

I was just about to say it, but something must have happened. I cannot alter in any way the server. I am powerless, and I have to beg for some decent functionality. This means I cannot install http://pecl.php.net/package/dio.

#### EDIT 2

I don't know if I am not allowed to use these functions at all, it's just that it has a php version higher than 5.0.5 , and it does not have the extension installed. So I am interested in a workaround, if I would have any idea how to find one...

#### EDIT 3

The actual problem is that I overwrite that protocol ("file") with a wrapper of my own, but I still need to read files, and being inside the wrapper class associated now with "file" I cannot restore the wrapper to default. So I have two options:
1. use low io operations to actually read files inside the wrapper associated to "file".
2. use another process to read the files and return the result in the other process, but this is problematic too

Comment: If this is not a server you control, and your ability to use these functions is refused by TOS so would be creating a work-around. I recommend a different server.

Comment: I don't believe there is a way. Have you asked your server admin if they can install the PECL package for you?

Comment: If you cannot install a PECL package onto the system, I would question your *need* for DIO-style functionality at all.

Comment: I asked them to install it, but they were reluctant to the idea. And I do need to have access to low io operations to bypass the "file" protocol.